# Use permalinks in config.yml

Tags: url, permalinks, ghost, hexo

My `categories` correspond to my menu items.
In my `config.yml` I specified for example:

```
menu:
  - name: phones
  - slug: phones
  - url: /categories/phones
```

Now how do I "remove" `categories` in the URL, so instead of
`blog.com/categories/phones` the menu item directs to `blog.com/phones`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to define categories permalinks in main **Hexo** `_config.yml`:

```
category_dir: /
```

Instead of:

```
category_dir: categories
```